# Nested for loops to print inside a rectangle frame

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I am trying to print a tree inside a rectangular frame, while my methods completely work i cant figure out on how to implement them with each other.

I have tried to print the tree method instead of spaces in the frame method but it doesnt work and now i cant figure out on what to do.

i am currently learning java so its still pretty new territory for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Weihnachtsbaum {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 20: ");
        int height = scan.nextInt();

        while((height < 1) || (height > 20))
        {
            System.out.println("Number not inside parameters!");
            System.out.print("Enter a number between 1 and 20: ");
            height = scan.nextInt();
        }
        
        //this is only to test that the outputs are right
        tree(height);
        System.out.println();
        frame(height);
        
    }

    static void tree(int height)
    {
        for(int i = 1;i <=height; i++)
        {
        //printing star
            if(i == 1)
            {
                for (int j = height - 2; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                for (int k = 1; k > 0; k--)
                {
                    System.out.println(">()<");
                }
            }
            //printing spaces
            for (int space = 1;space <= height - i; space++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            //branches
            for (int branch = 1; branch <= i; branch++)
            {
                
                System.out.print("/\\");
            }
            //next line
            System.out.println();

            //lower part of tree
            if(i == height)
            {
                for(int j = (height-1);j > 0;j--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for(int k = 2;k > 0;k--)
                {
                    
                    System.out.print("|");
                }

            }
        }
    }

    static void frame(int height)
    {

    for(int rows = 0; rows <= height+4; rows++)
    {
        for(int columns =  0; columns <= height*2+4; columns++)
        {
            if((rows == 0 && columns == 0) || (rows == height+4 && columns==0) || (columns == height*2+4 && rows == 0) || (rows == height+4 && columns == height*2+4))
            { 
            System.out.print("+");
            }
            else if( rows == 0 || rows == height+4)
            {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            else if(columns == 0 || columns == height*2+4)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have all the necessary bits figured out. You can create a single method to print the frame and the tree at the same time (create the frame as you create your tree).

Print the top and the bottom rows of the frame separately and the rest of the frame as you 'build' your tree.

Comment: You've done a lot of good work here. You've got to build your frame around your tree. One approach would be to have `frameTop`, `frameLeft`, `frameBottom` and `frameRight` methods and call them while building the tree.

Comment: So I think you can make your current code work as is by combining those two methods - they're not going to work in sequence, as all of one of their prints will occur either before or after the other, not "around". But, I think there's a better way for you to do this, especially while learning. Consider having the tree return a list of strings instead of printing them out as it runs; then you can have a separate method that takes a list of strings and adds a frame around them, and then finally a method that prints a list of strings.

Comment: Starting to think i dont understand what all this means because the loops are so complicated i actually dont know on how to add them.

Answer (score 1):

I think i might have done it even though the code is not the best looking but this should do it appreciate the help.
If you can help me to minimalize the code i would be thankful but if not this should be enough to get approved because it works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class weihnachtsbaum2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Bitte eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 20 eingeben: ");
        int height = scan.nextInt();

        while ((height < 1) || (height > 20))
        {
            System.out.println("Nicht gültige Zahl! ");
            System.out.print("Bite eine gültige Zahl zwischen 1 und 20 eingeben: ");
            height = scan.nextInt();
        }

        topFrame(height);
        middlePart(height);
        bottomPart(height);

    }

    static void topFrame(int height)
    {
        //Top of Frame
        for (int rows = 0; rows <= height; rows++)
        {
            for (int columns = 0; columns <= height+2; columns++)
            {
                if((rows == 0 && columns == 0) || (rows == height && columns==height+2))
                {
                    System.out.print("+");
                }
                else if( rows == 0 || rows == height)
                {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
            }
            if(rows == height)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    static void middlePart(int height)
    {
        for (int rows = 0; rows <= height-1; rows++)
        {   //spalten
            //printing star
            if(rows == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
                for (int j = height; j > 0; j--)
                {

                    System.out.print(" ");
                }

                for (int k = 1; k > 0; k--)
                {
                    System.out.print(">()<");
                }
                for(int x = 0; x <= height-1; x++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.print("|\n");

            }
            if(rows >= 0)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            for (int spaceLeft = 0;spaceLeft <= height - rows; spaceLeft++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            //branches
            for (int branch = 0; branch <= rows; branch++)
            {
                System.out.print("/\\");

            }
            for (int spaceRight = 0;spaceRight <= height - rows; spaceRight++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");

            }
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.println();
            if(rows == height-1)
            {
                System.out.print("|");
                for(int j = (height);j >= 0;j--)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                for(int k = 2;k > 0;k--)
                {

                    System.out.print("|");
                }
                for (int spaceRight = 0;spaceRight <= height; spaceRight++)
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");

                }
                System.out.print("|");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void bottomPart(int height)
    {
        //bottom of Frame
        for (int rows = 0; rows <= height; rows++)
        {   //spalten
            for (int columns = 0; columns <= height+2; columns++)
            {
                if((rows == 0 && columns == 0) || (rows == height && columns==height+2))
                {
                    System.out.print("+");
                }
                else if( rows == 0 || rows == height)
                {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
            }
            if(rows == height)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using loops is to use the [String.repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)) statement.  You can also use the same method to print the top and bottom borders.

```
public class Weihnachtsbaum2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Bitte eine Zahl zwischen 1 und 20 eingeben: ");
        int height = scan.nextInt();

        while ((height < 1) || (height > 20)) {
            System.out.println("Nicht gültige Zahl! ");
            System.out.print(
                    "Bite eine gültige Zahl zwischen 1 und 20 eingeben: ");
            height = scan.nextInt();
        }

        topAndBottom(height);
        middlePart(height);
        topAndBottom(height);

    }

    static void topAndBottom(int height) {
        // Top of Frame
        System.out.println("+" + "-".repeat(2 * (height+2)) + "+");

    }

    static void middlePart(int height) {
        String spaces = " ".repeat(height);
        String leftEnds = "|" + spaces;
        String rightEnds = spaces + "|";
        
        System.out.println(leftEnds + ">()<" + rightEnds);
        
        for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++) {
            spaces = " ".repeat(height-row+1);
            String left = "| " + spaces;
            String right = spaces + " |";
            String center = "/\\".repeat(row);
            
            System.out.println(left + center + right);
        }
        System.out.println(leftEnds + " || " + rightEnds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (not the cleanest code but does the work). Note a few changes - I have hardcoded the `height` but you can easily use the existing code to get input from the user. Also, the program does not print the star - take is as an exercise to get familiar with the code :)

```
public class MyTree {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // You can reuse your code to accept input here
        int height = 12;
        printTree(height);
    }

    public static void printTree(int height){
        printTop(height); // Prints the top row of frame
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            printRow(i+1, height); 
        }
        printTrunk(height); // Prints the tree stock/trunk
        printBottom(height); // Prints the bottom row of the frame
    }


    public static void printTop(int height){
        System.out.print("+");
        for(int i=0; i < (height*2) + 4; i++){
            System.out.print("-");
        }
        System.out.println("+");
    }

    private static void printBottom(int height){
        printTop(height);
    }

    private static void printSpaces(int spaces) {
        for(int i=0; i<spaces; i++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    private static void printRow(int rowNum, int height){
        int spaces = (height - rowNum) + 3;
        System.out.print("|");
        printSpaces(spaces-1);

        for(int i=0; i<rowNum; i++){
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }

        printSpaces(spaces-1);
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    private static void printTrunk(int height) {
        System.out.print("|");
        printSpaces(height + 1);
        System.out.print("||");
        printSpaces(height + 1);
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Prints the tree (notice there is no star) like below for input 10:

[image: Tree No Star]

Feel free to improve the code to your liking (a lot of scope there)